# Airflow Not Sending Errors to Sentry Automatically

Tags: python, airflow, sentry, airflow-2.x

I am having trouble configuring Airflow to automatically send error messages to Sentry.

I have set `sentry_on` and `sentry_dsn` in environment variables (`AIRFLOW__SENTRY__SENTRY_ON` and `AIRFLOW__SENTRY__SENTRY_DSN`), and these appear in the Airflow GUI Admin > Configuration display.  From the Sentry docummentation (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/airflow/) this should be enough to send error messages to Sentry on exceptions.

But when I deliberately throw an exception (example below) no error is sent to Sentry.

(I am confident that the `sentry_dsn` value works, as our code has custom code that we use in failure callbacks that does send error messages to Sentry.)

Reading the Airflow and sentry-python code, it seems that exceptions when running a task should automatically be sent to Sentry because `TaskInstance._run_raw_task` is decorated with `Sentry.enrich_errors`.  `enrich_errors` calls `sentry_sdk.capture_exception` which ultimately sends the error message to Sentry.

But I am not sure that `Sentry.enrich_errors` is being called.  I have written code patching it (also below) to log the call, but when the exception is thrown nothing is logged.  (Perhaps there is something wrong with the patching code?  Similar code patching `TaskInstance._run_raw_task` did result in log messages.)

Here is my code deliberately raising an `Exception` and patching `Sentry.enrich_errors`:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import wraps

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.configuration import conf
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sentry import Sentry

# Verify that the sentry_on configuration variable is set to True
logging.info("sentry_on is %s" % str(conf.getboolean("sentry", "sentry_on", fallback=False)))


class MySentry:
    def enrich_errors(self, func):
        """ Patch for enrich_errors to log if it has been called.  """

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(_self, *args, **kwargs):
            logging.info("MySentry.enrich_errors has been called")
            return func(_self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

# Sentry.enrich_errors = MySentry.enrich_errors

def throw_exception_function():
    raise Exception("still another exception thrown on purpose, no DAG or Task on_failure_callback, patch enrich_errors")


with DAG(
    dag_id="deliberate_exception__patch_enrich_errors",
    default_args={
        "owner": "DAG owner",
        "depends_on_past": False,
        "start_date": datetime(2017, 1, 1),
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=0),
    },
    description="Deliberately throws exception without on_failure_callback for DAG or task; patches enrich_errors",
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
) as dag:

    Sentry.enrich_errors = MySentry.enrich_errors

    exception_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="exception_task",
        python_callable=throw_exception_function,
    )
```

Please note that this code does not send errors to Sentry when the patching is commented out.

Why isn't my configuration automatically sending error messages to Sentry?
Why isn't `Sentry.enrich_errors` being called?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/21784

I do not know why errors are not being sent but a PR is there to fix the enrichment.